# Using base controller's object in layout page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We have below model classes **LayoutModel** and **EmployeeModel** :

```
public class LayoutModel
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeModel
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}
```

and we have a **BaseController** which initializes the **LayoutModel** object:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public LayoutModel layoutModel;

    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        layoutModel = new LayoutModel();
        layoutModel.CompanyName = "Microsoft";
    }
}
```

Then we have a **EmployeeController** which uses **BaseController** like this:

```
public class EmployeeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult GetEmployees()
    {
        EmployeeModel empModel = GetEmployees(this.layoutModel);
        return View("GetEmployees", empModel);
    }

    private EmployeeModel GetEmployees(LayoutModel layoutModel) {
        EmployeeModel empModel = new EmployeeModel();
        empModel.EmployeeName = "John";
        return empModel;
    }
}
```

We have a **GetEmployees.cshtml** view which uses **MainLayout.cshtml** as layout:

```
@model MvcTest.Models.EmployeeModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MainLayout.cshtml";
}
@section ContentBody{
     Employee Name: @Model.EmployeeName
}
```

**MainLayout.cshtml** code is like this:

```
@{
Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Company Name: **How to display layoutModel.CompanyName here? There can be many fields like CompanyName in layoutModel which will be access here.**</h1>
   @RenderSection("ContentBody")
</body>
</html>
```

Basically we have a LayoutModel class which we are initializing in BaseController and then we want to use in all of our controllers like EmployeeController. We are now able to access LayoutModel  object in EmployeeController.

**But we also want to access LayoutModel object in MainLayout.cshtml. How can we access it in MainLayout.cshtml?** Above LayoutModel class is just an example, we have many fields inside it which we want to access in different controllers and MainLayout.cshtml

Thank you.

Comment: A very simple solution can be using a viewbag that contains all the data of  "LayoutModel".So assign a viewbag with all "LayoutModel" data. And you can simply get that viewbag data into any view from any controller if you inherited the base controller.

Comment: Is there any alternate option as we woud like to avoid using viewbag? Basically we want to initialize LayoutModel and then use it in layout page's view and all controller actions.